# Props not passing down to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to pass a state function `setMyChoice` as a prop to a `GamePlay` component in a rock paper scissors Nextjs application so as to produce a value for comparison. In the gameplay component, I am passing a prop to a component `PlayButtons` as shown below.  In the `PlayButtons`, i can't access the value set by the function `setChoice` that is to be compared with the random value generated to determine whether the player has won, lost or draw. Kindly assist .The code samples are shown below.

```
//index.js
        const [myChoice, setMyChoice] = useState("")
        <Gameplay advanced={advancedMode} setMyChoice={setMyChoice} />
```

GamePlay.js

```
//GamePlay.js
const Gameplay = ({ setMyChoice }) => {
  const setChoice = (e) => {
    setMyChoice(e.target.dataset.id);
  };
return (
      <PlayButtons  setChoice={setChoice} />

);
}
```

PlayButtons.js

```
function PlayButtons({setChoice  }) {
  return (
<div className={styles.doublegrid}>
          <Link href="/Game" passHref>
          <button onClick={setChoice}  className={`${styles.paper} ${styles.circle}`}>
            <span className={styles.wrapper}>
            <Image src={icon_paper} alt=""/>
            </span>
          </button>
          </Link>
          <Link href="/Game" passHref>
          <button
            onClick={setChoice}
            className={`${styles.scissors1} ${styles.circle}`}
          >
            <span className={styles.wrapper}>
            <Image src={icon_scissors} alt="" />
            </span>
          </button>
          </Link>
          <Link href="/Game" passHref>
            <button  onClick={setChoice} className={`${styles.rock} ${styles.circle}`}>
            <span className={styles.wrapper}>
            <Image src={icon_rock} alt="" />
            </span>
          </button>
          </Link>
        
        </div>
      )}
    </div>

);
}
```

Game.js

```
function Game({ score, myChoice, setScore, advanced, setChoice }) {
  const [house, setHouse] = useState("");
  const [playerWin, setPlayerWin] = useState("");

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(3);

  const newHousePick = () => {
    const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors", "lizard", "spock"];
    setHouse(choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    newHousePick();
  }, []);

  const Result = () => {
    if (myChoice === "rock" && house === "scissors") {
      setPlayerWin("win");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "rock" && house === "paper") {
      setPlayerWin("lose");
      setScore(score - 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "rock" && house === "lizard") {
      setPlayerWin("lose");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "lizard" && house === "rock") {
      setPlayerWin("lose");
      setScore(score - 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "lizard" && house === "spock") {
      setPlayerWin("lose");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "spock" && house === "lizard") {
      setPlayerWin("lose");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "spock" && house === "scissors") {
      setPlayerWin("win");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "spock" && house === "lizard") {
      setPlayerWin("win");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "lizard" && house === "spock") {
      setPlayerWin("lose");
      setScore(score - 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "scissors" && house === "lizard") {
      setPlayerWin("win");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "lizard" && house === "scissors") {
      setPlayerWin("lose");
      setScore(score - 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "lizard" && house === "paper") {
      setPlayerWin("win");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "paper" && house === "lizard") {
      setPlayerWin("lose");
      setScore(score - 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "spock" && house === "rock") {
      setPlayerWin("win");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "rock" && house === "spock") {
      setPlayerWin("lose");
      setScore(score - 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "scissors" && house === "paper") {
      setPlayerWin("win");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "scissors" && house === "rock") {
      setPlayerWin("lose");
      setScore(score - 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "paper" && house === "rock") {
      setPlayerWin("win");
      setScore(score + 1);
    } else if (myChoice === "paper" && house === "scissors") {
      setPlayerWin("lose");
      setScore(score - 1);
    } else {
      setPlayerWin("draw");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.selection}>
      myChoice : {myChoice} <br/>
      HouseChoice: {house} <br/>
      Result: 
      {playerWin == "win" && <h1>You win</h1>}
      {playerWin == "lose" && <h1>You lose</h1>}
      {playerWin == "draw" && <h1>You draw</h1>}
      
      </div>

  );
}

export default Game;
```

Comment: I don't see any relation between `Game.js` and other components

Comment: When you create parent to child prop passing, parents' useState doesn't propagate to child as expected. Better use useEffect on child components in order to observe any prop changed. Its some what complicated issue let me know you need more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In `index.js` you're setting states using the `useState` hook. However it's not clear to me on which component that applies ?

Then, in your component `Gameplay`, `setChoice` is a function. Which means, I believe, that you're passing a function down to `Gameplay` as a prop. But that function doesn't return any value.

So you have these 2 issues; you might want to clarify what states and props apply to which component(s) to solve the problem.